# How can I automatically associate a json object key with a multidimensional form field?

Tags: javascript, json, forms, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to dynamically populate form fields based on whether or not a json array key exists with the same name.

This is json returned over an ajax call to the server:

```
{
    "title":"My Item Title",
    "product_description":{  
       "1":{  
          "name":"My Item",
          "description":"My Description"
       }
    },
    "image":"main.jpg",
    "additional_image":[  
        {
           "image":"img1.jpg",
           "sort":1
        },
        {
           "image":"img2.jpg",
           "sort":2
        }
    ],
    "model":"123",
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

My html form is like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="title"/>
    <input type="text" name="product_description[1][name]"/>
    <input type="text" name="product_description[1][description]"/>
    <input type="text" name="image"/>
    <input type="text" name="additional_image[0][image]"/>
    <input type="text" name="additional_image[0][sort]"/>
    <input type="text" name="additional_image[1][image]"/>
    <input type="text" name="additional_image[1][sort]"/>
    <input type="text" name="model"/>
    <input type="text" name="quantity"/>
</form>
```

And my current javascript is like this. There is probably a better way than using "for ...in" as the "key" only returns the parent "product_description" structure and not the underlying object. I try to check for the object, but it is not dynamic.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'path/to/callback',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
    success: function(json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                if (typeof(json[key]) == 'object') {
                    var obj = json[key];
                    for (var prop in obj) {
                        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                            if (typeof(json[key]) == 'object') {
                                    var obj2 = obj[prop];
                                    for (var prop2 in obj2) {
                                        $('input[name="'+key+'['+prop+']['+obj[prop]+'['+prop2+']"]').val(json.key);
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $('input[name="'+key+'"]').val(json.key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is to use underscore's [**template**](http://underscorejs.org/#template) function.

This function allows you to inject values from a JSON object into a prepared string.
For your solution you can extract the appropriate value from the JSON by creating a dummy string and using the template function.

[**Example Plunkr here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/zoDB1FDTLFm9nvuq9l7B?p=info)

The bit that does all the work is:

```
var fields = $('form input[type="text"]');
$.each(fields, function(idx, item) {
   item.value = _.template('<%=' + item.name + '%>')(json);
});
```

This code takes an input field:
`<input type="text" name="json.object.array[0].value"/>`
and creates a template string: `<%=json.object.array[0].value%>`

Then it passes that string to underscore and you get the value :)

(Don't forget to include underscore in your html page)